# DockerFile call install msi

Tags: powershell, docker

I'm having a hard time installing an msi via Dockerfile. My Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest

RUN mkdir C:\temp 
RUN mkdir C:\temp\msis

COPY . "C:/temp/msis"
RUN powershell -version 5.0 -command { Start-process -Filepath "C:\temp\msis\mySetup.msi" -ArgumentList  "/qn" -PassThru | Wait-Process}
```

When running docker build via:

```
docker build -t myTools .
```

I get the following error:

```
Step 7/7 : RUN powershell -version 5.0 -command { Start-process -Filepath "C:\temp\msis\mySetup.msi" -ArgumentList  "/qn" -PassThru | Wait-Process}
---> Running in d6f9f65d96a9
'Wait-Process}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

If I build the container without the RUN step, and attach myself via `-it` to the running container and paste the command `powershell -version 5.0 -command { Start-process -Filepath "C:\temp\msis\mySetup.msi" -ArgumentList  "/qn" -PassThru | Wait-Process}` the MSI gets installed correctly.

Has anyone an idea this failure happens?

Thx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Possibly it's a PowerShell parsing problem.

Try these 2 lines instead of your last line:

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Start-Process 'C:\\temp\\msis\\mySetup.msi' '/qn' -PassThru | Wait-Process;
```

After that you can revert to cmd.exe if you wish:

```
SHELL ["cmd", "/C"]
```

Comment: Thx for the quick response. Your answer saved my day!

Comment: I was struggling with those hard-to-invoke msi installers 2 weeks ago, it's definitely not intuitive.